# Robolectric throwing ResourceNotFound exception

Tags: android, robolectric

Robolectric read the res file within the `/build/intermediates/res` during runtime. However, when doing the test, it threw a `ResourceNotFoundException`. My Android application has many different flavors, different flavors has different `applicationIds`. If this is the issue, is there any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known issue when flavors have different application ids. You can use the packageName property to fix this issue. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2110

```
@Config(packageName = "app.base.package.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom roboletric test runner class to tell roboletric where the resources classes are:

```
public class CustomRobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {

    public CustomRobolectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    // Fix for the NotFound error with openRawResource()
    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
        String res = String.format("../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/%1$s/%2$s", BuildConfig.FLAVOR, BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE);
        String asset = "src/test/assets";
        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifest), Fs.fileFromPath(res), Fs.fileFromPath(asset));
    }
}
```

In your test class, specify the custom test runner class like:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class DataServiceTest {
}
```